# position of smaller string within a larger string

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g

I have to find the position of a string within a larger string in pl/sql.

Lets say the string is: 'allthebest all the best'
I have to get the position of the string "the" only when it is a separate word and not part of a string.
In the above case, the position of the word "the" should be 16 corresponding to the indepedant word and not 4. The occurance of the word "the" in "allthebest" should not be considered.

Tried this:

```
select regexp_instr('allthebest all the best',' the ') from dual;
```

Ofcourse, it works when there is a space preceeding and following the word "the". 
But, does not work for cases where the string is : 'allthebest all best the' (note: there is no trailing space after the word 'the')

How to make it such that it only looks for independant words within an input string that is not itself a part of a smaller string in pl/sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the pattern `'([^[:alpha:]]|^)the([^[:alpha:]]|$)'`

That's "any non-alphabetic OR the start of the string" followed by the word you're looking for followed by "any non-alphabetic OR the end of the string"

Comment: thanks James. It works. But, i want to understand how you arrived at it. Can you point me to a good reading on what these regexp symbols here stand for and how to apply these notations so that I can understand them and start using them ? When I google for these, I get lost with lots of material that i am not sure which one would give the best information. Right now, to be honest, they seem like a bunch of characters to me, an untrained eye that is !

Comment: what if the word "the" is a variable in the pl/sql code. Append does not seem to work here: '([^[:alpha:]]|^) || <variable string to search for> || ([^[:alpha:]]|$)'

Comment: @Casey: This is what I used for the syntax: http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-10764.html

Comment: @Casey: The append should work, but hard to tell from the the comment, but I think you written it wrong.  Remember it must ba a string (in quotes), bars, variable, bars, string in quotes, so, `'([^[:alpha:]]|^)' ||` *<variable string to search for>* `|| '([^[:alpha:]]|$)'`

Comment: Nice.  A similar approach: '(^|\s)the(\s|$)'

Comment: @tbone: As I recall, `\s` only matches whitespace, while we need it to also match punctuation.  *And*, if the reference I checked is to be believed, it doesn't work on Oracle's implementation of RegExes anyway.

Comment: Thanks James for your followup.

Comment: @JamesCurran why does it need to also match punctuation? (must have missed that part in the OP). So we want 'the#test' to match?  (And \s does work with Oracle)

Comment: @tbone: Actually, I was think more of a comma or period following the word being search for, which you'd likely find if the string is an actual sentence.  And the OP's requirement was to find a string "when it is a separate word and not part of a string."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can simply break the string on the space character to generate "words" (a more sophisticated solution would be to also look for punctuation that indicates the end of a word), you can simply add a space at the beginning and end of the string and subtract 1 from the result (to account for the fact that you added the extra space at the beginning)

```
instr( ' ' || <<your string>> || ' ', ' the ' ) - 1
```